# How to send data to activities from rxAndroid custom subscriber?

Tags: android, rx-android, event-bus, subscriber

I am developing one application and trying to replace EventBus with RxAndroid hence i created Observable and i have subscribed to my own Subscriber.i am receiving data successfully below is the code-

```
Observable.just(uPnPDevices)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new MySubscriber());
```

MySubsCriber class method-

```
 @Override
        public void onNext(UPnPDevices uPnPDevices) {
      /*rest code is here*/
     //i want to post data from here to all activities 
    }
```

Now my concern is do i have to send data to Activities if again i have to use interface or EventBus then there is no use of using rxAndroid i found in blogs that you can replace EventBus with rxAndorid completely.

Is there any way activity can receive data from Subscriber.
I would appreciate if any one can help me on this or some idea would be great .

Comment: [one example](http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/) of RxBus implementation